# Data science project examples based on Cookie Cutter Data science template

Tags: python, reproducible-research

Interested by production ready data science project do you have any public github reference concrete implementation?

As an example i found this project template structure https://drivendata.github.io/cookiecutter-data-science/ but can't find any simple project (like titanic one or other) that could fit this structure on public github; meanwhile it would be wonderful to help newcomers as me!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a project that answer my needs: https://github.com/hackalog/bus_number, if it can help other ;)

Comment: Looks like they have upgraded to a new mod of the cookiecutter data science template: https://github.com/hackalog/easydata. Same people. I'm still getting to know it, but it looks like EasyData helps with maintaining metadata, and has a strong makefile to help with workflow.